# Security rule fails on nested document firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to add a document data in to sub collection but i am facing permission dined what could by causing the issue ?

```js
// Add Main Chat Doc
const colRef = collection(db, 'data-chats', _authContext.currentUser.uid, 'clients', id, 'masseges');
  await addDoc(colRef, {
    masseges: [],
    createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
  });
```

Chat collection security rules:

```
match /data-chats/{id}/clients/{clientId}/masseges {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting a different outcome?  Your rule path doesn't match the document path from your code.  The rule would never allow this code to add a document.

Comment: @DougStevenson I put wrong collection typo when adding to stack. not working.

Comment: The path should match a doc path as mentioned by Doug so the rule should be `match /data-chats/{id}/clients/{clientId}/masseges/{msgId}`